# python requests API conection not working

Tags: python-requests

I am trying to connect to groupon's API and this is the code provided by groupon itself:

```
import requests #requires "requests" package
response = requests.get('https://scm.commerceinterface.com/api/v3/get_orders',
                       data={'supplier_id':'1', 'token':'xYRPKcoakMoiRzWgKLV5TqPSdNAaZQT'}).json()
```

I am trying with my token and user ID but I get a negative response

```
print(response['success']
```

Output:

```
FALSE
```

I would like to know it the  where the problem might be

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it translating the Curl script to Python:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    }


activities = requests.get('https://baud.teamwork.com/crm/api/v2/activities.json', headers=headers).json()
```